# How can I make my code return a phrase if two parameters are equal?

Tags: python, control-flow

```py
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  return max(num1, num2, num3)
  if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
    return "It's a tie"
```

This code isn't returning "It's a tie" when it should be. Might be a simple error as new to coding but struggling to understand.
Thanks!

Comment: Consider tracing through your code one step at a time. Is there something you encounter before the `if` statement that might preclude it from running?

Answer (score 1):

This code is never reaching the conditional statement because the return statement will always exit the function. Instead write:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  m = max(num1, num2, num3)
  if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
    return "It's a tie"
  else:
    return m
```

This will return "It's a tie" if any two of the numbers are the same, otherwise the largest of the three.

Alternatively this is a more efficient way of writing it:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
    return "It's a tie"
  else:
    return max(num1, num2, num3)
```

This means the maximum is only calculated if there is no tie so the function is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

At the first `return` the function exits. Control flow never reaches the conditional.  Perhaps you meant the following, checking for a tie, otherwise returning the maximum number.

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
    return "It's a tie"
  else:
    return max(num1, num2, num3)
```

---

As a sidenote, another way to check for a tie would be to check the length of a `set` created from the three numbers. A `set` will not contain duplicates, so if it's less than `3`, there must be a tie.

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if len(set([num1, num2, num3])) != 3:
    return "It's a tie"
  else:
    return max(num1, num2, num3)
```

---

Rather than returning a string from your function in the event of a tie, you may wish to raise an exception so the calling code can handle that situation as it sees fit.

```py
class TieException(Exception): pass

def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
  if len(set([num1, num2, num3])) != 3:
    raise TieException
  return max(num1, num2, num3)

try:
  print(max_num(1, 2, 2))
except TieException:
  print("It's a tie")
```

Note that `else` is not necessary here because raising the exception also forces control flow to leave the function. The `return` will not be evaluated if the fist condition is true.

---

You might *also* use `count` to check for a tie situation.

```
def max_nums(num1, num2, num3):
  nums = [num1, num2, num3]
  if any(nums.count(n) > 1 for n in nums):
    raise TieException
  return max(nums)
```

This has the benefit of scaling so that any number of numbers can be passed in. Though you may wish to raise a `TypeError` exception if no numbers are provided.

```
def max_nums(*nums):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    raise TypeError("max_nums requires at least one argument")
  if any(nums.count(n) > 1 for n in nums):
    raise TieException
  return max(nums)
```

Of course, we also don't need to know the count. This would be very inefficient for a large list. Instead we just need to check if *any* number is *in* the rest of the list after it. This will stop as soon as it finds a duplicate, indicating a "tie."

```
def max_nums(*nums):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    raise TypeError("max_nums requires at least one argument")
  if any(x in nums[i+1:] for i, x in enumerate(nums)):
    raise TieException
  return max(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You (roughly) wrote:

> ```
> return a_value
>
> if condition:
>     return different_value
>
> return None
> ```

Please understand that the initial `return`
prevents the rest of the code from running.
We call it "unreachable code".
The flow of control transfers when we
hit the `return`, so subsequent
statements are never even considered
for evaluation.

Also, falling off the end of a
Python function (the `else` clause of your `if`)
will default to returning a `None` object.

You want to **first** evaluate the `if`,
and **then** `return` the numeric
maximum value.

---

Python is a dynamically typed language,
so it is *kind of* OK to have mixed
return types, such as `str` / `int` as
we see here.

But it's not a best practice.
It tends to make it hard for the
calling function to consume the
return value.
For example, the expression

```
1 + max_num(a, b, c)
```

will evaluate nicely on some of your tests, but it will raise an
error on e.g. `1 + max_num(2, 2, 3)`.
This example also highlights a code
defect in the OP logic.

Note it is quite different
from `1 + max_num(2, 3, 3)`,
where there truly *is* a legitimate
tie for maximum.

When designing a public API, consider
how the consumer will use the return
value. In this case, you might want
to return a tuple:

```
m = max(num1, num2, num3)
is_tie = (   (num1 == num2 == m)
          or (num1 == num3 == m)
          or (num2 == num3 == m))
return m, is_tie
```

OTOH if consumer will merely print it,
then the current API is just fine.

Comment: _An_ approach to handling the "It's a tie" scenario might be to raise an exception. The caller can assume the return value of `max_num` is `int` and choose how it wants to handle the `TieException`.